# Giving temporary permission to other apps for Content provider data

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider, android-permissions

I have a Data manager application which hosts the Content provider and the data under it (says `App PROVIDER`), I wish to provide `TEMPORARY` permission to other applications to access(`READ`) the data stored under `App PROVIDER`, these receiver apps are called as `App Receiver`.

I have successfully achieved the part of providing data to the `App Receivers` by using `android:readPermission` and `<permission android:name="...READ"/>`  on the provider side and `<uses-permission android:name="..."/>` on the `App receivers` side.

Problem: The problem arises when I have to provide temporary permission to these `Receiver apps`, I need to implement a licensing mechanism by which I need to pull back the permissions from these `Receiver Apps` whenever the license expires for these `Receiver apps`.

I have been going through the `GrantURIpermission` method but couldn't find much on it or its implementation, it would be really helpful if anyone could help me out with this.

Comment: `I need to pull back the permissions from these Receiver Apps`. You program those apps too? And where do you want to pull back the permission? In the provider app or in that specific receiver app?

Comment: @greenapps 
`You program those apps too?`  No i don't make those apps
I just want to restrict the  `Receiver Apps` from accessing the provider data if their license expires, so i wish to pull the permission from the `Receiver apps`

Comment: So you want to withdraw the permission with code in the provider app? That was what i asked. And how would the provider app know that the licence of other apps are expired?

Comment: If the receiver app knows that the licence is expired then it would be very easy for the app to release the permission. If that is what you want. But if you do not code that app...

Comment: @greenapps the provider app acts as a middleware to update the data, and should act as a gateway for providing the third party apps access to that data, is there anyway we can revoke already given permission to the ` `receivers`

Comment: For the third time: Where do you want to do that? Who will be doing that? Who should care for it?

Comment: ok, so `So you want to withdraw the permission with code in the provider app? ` Yes this is the exact thing i want to achieve.
`And how would the provider app know that the licence of other apps are expired?` This would be updated by a server, and license expiry would trigger denial of permissions to receivers.

I hope to have cleared these doubts

Comment: Does the provider app know from which receiver app a request is coming?

Comment: `Does the provider app know from which receiver app a request is coming? ` yes, it does know about it.

Comment: Well than it could just not honour the request. What is the problem doing so?

Comment: @greenapps once the `App receiver` connects with the ContentProvider with all the permissions from the  `App provider` the app provider needs to  at some point of time stop the `Receiver` from accessing the Content provider (may be by changing access permission or something), how is it possible i wanted to ask

Comment: Yes continue talking about permissions. But i suggested that requests would not be honored any more. You are not even reacting on my suggestion. That does not feel good. `once the App receiver connects with the ContentProvider `. Isn't the app receiver connecting with the app provider? Anyhow why not not honer the request?

Comment: I am sorry, lets have conversation over the chat, i might have missed out on something. do you mind connecting there?

Comment: Yes. I mind. I do not like chat.